# Regular Expression for recognizing files with following patterns az.4.0.0.119.tgz

Tags: regex, actionscript

I am trying to find a regular expression that will recognize files with the pattern as az.4.0.0.119.tgz. I have tried the regular expression below:

```
([a-z]+)[.][0-9]{0,3}[.][0-9]{0,3}[.][0-9]{0,3}[.]tgz
```

But, no luck. Can anyone please point me in the right direction.

Regards,
Shreyas

Comment: What language, operating system, shell version, ... are you talking about?

Comment: Doing it in actionscript as a filter to an arraycollection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to use a simple regex like this:

```
^([a-z]+)\.(?:[0-9]+\.)+tgz$
```

Comment: Very nice ... I just had to remove the '^' to get it to work ... also can you explain the metachars ? and : used in here.

Comment: `?:` is used as non-capturing group here. Pls check this http://www.regular-expressions.info/ for details.

Answer (score 2):

You just forgot one number part:

```
([a-z]+)[.][0-9]{0,3}[.][0-9]{0,3}[.][0-9]{0,3}[.][0-9]{0,3}[.]tgz
```

or

```
([a-z]+)[.]([0-9]{0,3}[.]){4}tgz
```

Depending on where and how you use the regex, you might want to surround it in `^...$`.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern has 4 chiffers group, your regexp only 3.